# Tcl: Using lower version packages in the higher version package

Tags: tcl

I am new to tcl and am trying to extend one of the existing packages.

```
package provide trial 1.0

namespace eval ::trial {
    namespace export create delete
}

proc ::trial::create { arg1 arg2 } {
    ....
}

proc ::trial::delete { arg1 } {
    ....
}
```

I want to write package trial 2.0 which can add one more proc status. How can I do this? And how can I overload create proc and call the version 1.0 create proc?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be at most one call to `package provide` for the named package per interpreter. It's possible to make a `pkgIndex.tcl` that describes how to provide multiple versions of the same package, but it isn't a common thing to do. Without that, you've got the problem that you can't really safely refer to the implementation of another version of the package as you don't know that it is going to be installed in exactly the same place.

Instead, it's usual to just copy the code and only then modify. Trying to avoid duplicating one or two fairly small files is typically more trouble than it is worth!

As a point of order, just adding another command would usually be just reason to go from `1.0` to `1.1`, not go to `2.0`, since code that expects just the old interface would most likely work fine with the updated version. But that does depend on whether the addition is semantically-compatible, and it's in general hard to make code work that out for you as it actually depends on the call orchestration pattern, and that's potentially non-trivial to compute (though often easy in easy cases).